# Order by takes forever for one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm using MySql. I got to simplify a query.
The **(query is just for understanding)** original is as bellow:

```
SELECT id from (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY C1, C2) ORDER BY C1
```

This one works fine, takes few seconds.

And the simplified version should be:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY C1
```

But the second query is taking time forever for a large table.
**Both C1 and C2 are indexed separately.**

Please help,

**Show index results**

Primary id 4312718 candidates

C1 130688 candidates

C2 22 candidates

Comment: Could you show the index definitions? `show index from tbl_name`

Comment: Run EXPLIAN, in the MysqL Workbench http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ or similar GUI DB utility because they give much beter output.

Comment: @Andomar I edited the question with index definitions

Comment: @DavidSoussan EXPLAIN did work! Where I noticed indexes are not been used in the first query so I added IGNORE INDEX(C1) which did the work. It is weird though.

Comment: @DavidSoussan please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run EXPLIAN, in the MysqL Workbench mysql.com/products/workbench or similar GUI DB utility because they give much beter output.

Comment: The problem which EXPLAIN explained was with the indexing. The two queries was using two different indexes. To overcome it I could used FORCE INDEX or IGNORE INDEX

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected result for large tables. Try using `LIMIT 100;` or whatever You need.